# want to set the border to table by exporting data to excel sheet in codeingiter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having problem setting a border to a table.

When I export the table from an Excel sheet I get the values without a border.

I want to fix the border to the table but it shows an error.

```
<div class="dvData">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Email Id</th>
        <th>Mobile Number</th>
        <th>Residential Address</th>
        <th>Temporary Address</th>
        <th>Company name</th>
        <th>Company type</th>
        <th>Bank Name</th>
        <th>Branch Name</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php echo $result->first_name;?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $result->email;?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $result->phone_num;?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $result->address1;?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $result->address2;?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $result->company_name;?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $result->customer_type;?></td>

      </tr>

      <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

this is my script code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dvData").hide();
  EditableTable.init();

  $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('.dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

this is php code:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="btnExport" value=" Export" />
```

without setting border am getting output like this .. refer noborder.png table contain data with no border.

[image]

When I'm setting  border value to table am getting output like this.. border.png

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A58P3.png)

```
<table border="1" width="1000px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make this file, suppose export.php :

```
                    <?php
                         header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
                         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=listing-export.xls");
                    ?>
                    <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Customer Name</th>
                              <th>Email Id</th>
                              <th>Mobile Number</th>
                              <th>Residential Address</th>
                              <th>Temporary Address</th>
                              <th>Company name</th>
                              <th>Company type</th>
                              <th>Bank Name</th>
                              <th>Branch Name</th>

                          </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                          <?php

                               foreach ($results as $result)
                               {

                               ?>
                          <tr>
                               <td><?php echo $result->first_name;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $result->email;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $result->phone_num;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $result->address1;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $result->address2;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $result->company_name;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $result->customer_type;?></td>

                          </tr>

                           <?php
                               }
                               ?>

                          </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Than make other file such as do_export.php and code as following :

```
<script>
   function exportfile()
   {
       var export_file = window.open("export.php","", "left=0,top=0,width=500,height=300,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0");
       export_file.focus(); 
   }
 </script>
 <input type="Button" value="Export" onclick="exportfile()" />
```

After making above two files, please run second file (do_export.php) and click on Export button.

Thanks...

Comment: it showing full data like (include dashboard items , sidebar, and table without border value..)

Comment: when i clicking that customer side bar icon automatically it shows its get downloaded and showing the excel file

Comment: missing table border in excel sheet